# SharePoint 2013 PowerShell: Modify term set global navigation items

Tags: powershell, managed-metadata, term-store, managed-navigation

Term Store Management: I need to modify a large number of items in the Managed Metadata store that are used for Global Navigation.

I can do this one-by-one in the browser, but there's loads to go through - is there a way that I can do this using PowerShell?

Comment: What kind of modifications do want to perform? Just renaming term sets or anything else?

Comment: Updating the "Sample Link or header" field (i.e. the URL)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at PnP PowerShell.  This is a collection of commandlets that extend the capability of PowerShell.  This article explains several capabilities PnP PowerShell provides for managing the Term Store:

https://medium.com/rapidcircle/pnp-powershell-maintain-all-your-termset-data-across-tenants-86ee26623097

Answer (score 0):

I found this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushalendra/2012/02/29/move-merge-and-rename-operations-on-managed-metadata-term-using-powershell/) which reads xml file and performs various operations on managed Metadata terms.

This link includes following operations:

1. Merge
2. Rename
3. Move

Comment: have you tried this?